# The method 'forEach' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

What I am trying to do is to fetch the value of the key on my Firebase Database.

**This is my code**

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:comment_app/post.dart';

final dataReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('posts/');
DatabaseReference savePost(Post post) {
  final id = dataReference.child('posts/').push();
  id.set(post.toJson());
  return id;
}

void updatePost(Post post, DatabaseReference id) {
  id.update(post.toJson());
}

Future<List<Post>> getAllMessages() async {

  
  DataSnapshot? dataSnapshot =
      (await dataReference.child('posts/').once()) as DataSnapshot;
    
  List<Post> posts = [];
 
  if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value){ //Error highlights the forEach here.
      Post post = createPost(value);
      post.setId(dataReference.child('posts/' + key));
      posts.add(post);
    });
  }
  return posts;
}
```

**Here is the code for post.dart**

```
import 'package:comment_app/authentication/database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Post {
  String body;
  String author;
  Set userLikes = {};
  late DatabaseReference _id;
  Post(this.body, this.author);
  void likePost(User users) {
    if (userLikes.contains(users.uid)) {
      userLikes.remove(users.uid);
    } else {
      userLikes.add(users.uid);
    }
    this.update();
  }

  void update() {
    updatePost(this, _id);
  }

  void setId(DatabaseReference id) {
    _id = id;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'author': author,
      'userLikes': userLikes.toList(),
      'body': body,
    };
  }
}



Post createPost(record) {
  
  Map<String, dynamic> attributes = {'author': '', 'userLikes': [], 'body': ''};
  record.forEach((key, value) => {attributes[key] = value});
  Post post = Post(attributes['body'], attributes['author']);
  post.userLikes = Set.from(attributes['userLikes']);
  return post;
}
```

I'm just starting to learn flutter with firebase and I am getting this error:

**This is the error**

> The method 'forEach' can't be unconditionally invoked because the
> receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.')
> or adding a null check to the target ('!').

[I'm trying to get the author and body of each key in my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVqvz.png)

Comment: please paste and format your code. Not a photo and especially not a link to a photo.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi I already edited my question, anyway thanks for the inforamation I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So the error is telling you that you want to run `something.forEach`. but flutter doesn't know if `something` is null, if it is null, it can't run foreach, so it is asking you to tell it what it should do if it is null. We first need to figure out what `something` is. You call `.forEach` twice in your code:

```
dataSnapshot.value.forEach
```

and

```
record.forEach
```

I don't know which might be causing the error, but if you look at the error message, it should tell you the exact line and file it is happening, so do try to figure it out by yourself.

On the first call, you already made sure `dataSnapshot.value` is not null by adding this line:

```
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
```

Normally, dart is smart enough to figure out `dataSnapshot.value` is not null, but I guess there is a chance it didn't, in such cases, where you know a value that **could be null, isn't**, you can use the `!` expression after a null value.

```
dataSnapshot.value!.forEach
```

Bare in mind that if `dataSnapshot.value` was null, your app would crash, so only use `!` when you **know** a value is not null. Also, as I said, dart is probably smart enough to know `dataSnapshot.value` is not null, so you probably don't need to do this, and the real culprit is probably `record`.

The second time you use it is in `record.forEach`, so let's look at the type of record to figure out weather it can be null or not:

```
Post createPost(record) {
  ...
}
```

What's this? You did not give  `record` any type! No wonder dart doesn't trust that it won't be null. Whatever `record` is supposed to be, make sure to add a type, if it can be null, then you should add the a null check before running like you did on `dataSnapshot`

Comment: The forEach error highlights this part >> dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value), so I think the forEach in post.dart is just fine, I also tried this "dataSnapshot.value!.forEach" and the error changed to this: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'. (Still the forEach error from dataSnapshot.value.forEach)

Comment: It is hard to fix this issue because you are working with a lot of dynamic values. And I don't know what those values are **supposed** to be. Can you try doing this? `(dataSnaoshot!.value! as List).forEach(` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Dart doesn't recognize that you already checked if
`dataSnapshot.value` is null:

```
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value){
```

###### To fix this issue you can simply add '!' in front of `value`:

```
    dataSnapshot.value!.forEach((key, value){
```

**2.** The `forEach` method comes up as undefined:

> The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'.dartundefined_method

This happens because `forEach` doesn't normally work inside a `Future<T>` function.

To get `forEach` to work as intended, you'd need to invoke it from `Future` first, which in this case won't work because you must pass `dataSnapshot.value` to the `forEach()` method and doing so breaks the code.

```dart
Future.forEach(elements, (element));  // This is an example of what it would look like
```

A typical way to deal with this issue is to restructure the code to fit a `for` loop or try something different.
I found that separating the `forEach()` method from a `Future<T>` function to a `Future` function to get it to run normally works just as well.

###### I had the same problem recently when trying a newer version of firebase, this was how I fixed it:

```dart
// New function using the regular Future, forEach() works normally
Future snapshotValue(dataSnapshot, posts) async {
  dataSnapshot.value!.forEach((key, value) {
    Post post = createPost(value);
    post.setId(databaseReference.child("posts/" + key));
    posts.add(post);
  });
}

// Future<t> function, only supports Future.forEach()
Future<List<Post>> getAllMessages() async {
  DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = (await databaseReference.child("posts/").once()).snapshot;
  List<Post> posts = [];
  if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    snapshotValue(dataSnapshot, posts);  // Insert the new function back in
  }
  return posts;
}
```

The code above was tested on `firebase_database: ^9.1.2` and `firebase_auth: ^3.6.4`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to re-write your code from:

```
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
  dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value){ //Error highlights the forEach here.
  Post post = createPost(value);
  post.setId(dataReference.child('posts/' + key));
  posts.add(post);
});
```

}

into this:

```
...
if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
  for(var entries in dataSnap.value){
      Post post = createPost(entries.value);
      post.setId(dataReference.child('posts/' + entries.key));
      posts.add(post);
  }
}
...
```

This is [documented online in the dart-lang linter](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls.html).